# How to implement ASP.NET MVC Razor code that will render as links to internal network shared directories?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, network-share

At our company, we creating a IntrAnet online web application using ASP.NET MVC framework ( with ASP.NET MVC Razor ).

Since it is internally used, we want one of the ASP.NET Views to have links to one of our internal network shared directories ( e.g., \\blah-blah\blah-network-share-blah-blah\yada\yadayada\ )

Could someone please show me sample ASP.NET MVC Razor code that will ulimately render as a link within the view that can be clicked so that the network shared directory shows up for the user?

Comment: Just make an anchor tag and set its href to the path?

Comment: For a better solution, create an user to the shared directory, in the website you are hosting, make the identity that is running under the appPool the user, you can then have multiple configured folder access